# Google Data Studio: Date Range Filter Error

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

I am creating Google Data studio dashboard using Google BigQuery Custom query datasource.

I am getting following error in Datastudio when I apply date filter on tables/charts

```
The query returned an error.

Failed to parse input string "2018-04-15"
Error ID: 1f94c822
```

This is my Date Dimension field passed from BigQuery:

```
PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d',  date)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIzIh.png)

Could anyone help to identify the issue with date ?

Answer (score 0):

Given the input string you mentioned, I'd try

```
PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d',  date)
```

(with dashes)

Comment: I did it, now the error is :The query returned an error.

Failed to parse input string "20180401"
in BigQuery

Comment: Aw, looks like the tables/data has dates in two different formats maybe?

Comment: I am having a union on 2 tables date format on 1 table is yyyymmdd other is yyyy-mm-dd. where i have used this functionFORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", cast(date as DATE)) to match date formats

Comment: @Mayank, if you have resolved the issue, can you post it as an "Answer"?